# sql iif statement join tables questions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I want to produce the result:

```
table name: HWData
policy number:        number of residents:   factor:
100                     2                      1
101                     4                      1.25
102                     7                      2
103                     99                     2
104                     1                      0.85
```

using the rules:

```
table name: Tier_Occupancy
number of residents:   factor:
1                       0.85
2                       1  
3                       1.10
4                       1.25
5                       1.5
6 or above              2.0
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
HWData.[Policy Number], 
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] = 1, Tier_Occupancy.Factor,1 ), 
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] = 2, Tier_Occupancy.Factor, 1), 
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] = 3, Tier_Occupancy.Factor, 1), 
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] = 4, Tier_Occupancy.Factor, 1), 
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] = 5, Tier_Occupancy.Factor, 1), 
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] >= 6, Tier_Occupancy.Factor, 1)

FROM HWData 
INNER JOIN Tier_Occupancy ON HWData.[Number of Residents]=Tier_Occupancy.[Number of Residents]

ORDER BY HWData.[Policy Number];
```

My question is it does show the result but it shows `1 1 1 1 1 1` for policy number 100
and it shows `1 1 1 1.25 1 1` for policy number 101 but I don't want that: I just want to show 1 for policy number 100 and 1.25 for policy number 101.

I am using 2007 Microsoft Access's SQL.

Comment: What version of SQL has an `iif` function? What does it do?

Comment: What is your RDBMS? MS-SQL Server does not have iif as a function. Is it yiur own UDF?

Comment: sorry to add, i m actually using 2007 Microsoft Access's SQL server, if that makes sense to any of you...

Comment: So, what do you get. I assume you get a lot of columns. Is that your problem?

Comment: Albin, you are correct, i dont want that many columns, I just want the result column solely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this

```
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] = 1, Tier_Occupancy.Factor,1 ), 
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] = 2, Tier_Occupancy.Factor, 1), 
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] = 3, Tier_Occupancy.Factor, 1), 
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] = 4, Tier_Occupancy.Factor, 1), 
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] = 5, Tier_Occupancy.Factor, 1), 
iif( HWData.[Number of Residents] >= 6, Tier_Occupancy.Factor, 1)
```

with this

```
Tier_Occupancy.Factor
```

The join needs to be fixed. It is where you need to use the IIF.

```
ON iif(HWData.[Number of Residents]>5,6,HWData.[Number of Residents]) = Tier_Occupancy.[Number of Residents]
```

and drop the " or above" from the last entry in the Tier_Occupancy table's last "number of residents" entry. That should be a numeric column.

Also, don't forget to select the number of residents column as you said you wanted in your result.

Comment: why not? I'm limiting that value to not be larger than 6.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
HWData.[Policy Number], 
   (select top 1 Tier_Occupancy.Factor from Tier_Occupancy 
    where Tier_Occupancy.[Number of Residents] <= HWData.[Number of Residents]
   order by Tier_Occupancy.[Number of Residents] desc) as factor
FROM HWData 

ORDER BY HWData.[Policy Number];
```